# Landsat 5 missing archives in Africa

Tags: data-request, africa

I am trying to download Landsat 5 tile on USGS explorer from the Landsat Collection 1 and Landsat Collection 2 dataset in order to do temporal analysis. However, in Africa, I can only retrieve a few images between 1984 and 2002 (approximately one every two year). In other continent such as Europe, I can access all images (every 14 days).

Is it a USGS issue, or can I get the data somewhere else ?

PS : I am posting my issue here because custserv@usgs.gov has not answering to me.

Comment: Could you screenshot  it what you are seeing ?

Answer (score 1):

not sure about why. I am currently doing a project on Nigeria, and I have had issues finding particular images. I am using Landsat 8, 7 gave me murky images. Have you tried other landsat satellites?

Comment: I didn't found other satellites with this time coverage and this resolution. I also found an interesting resources that can help you : https://www.nature.com/articles/nature20584/figures/5